# Deploy ArcGIS Desktop on Azure VM

Tags: arcgis-desktop, deployment, azure

Trying to deploy ArcGIS desktop on a cloud VM. I'm single user licence, and I've found three different explanations -- On the ArcGIS site, the Azure site and none of them work.

It seems like it shouldn't be hard to do. I know how to deploy a VM but Azure wants me to add some crazy data management features I don't know if I need.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Thank you for taking the Tour. Unfortunately, you haven't linked the explanations (for which you only listed two), and you haven't explicitly listed what you have tried, so there isn't much for us to go on.